# Как создать форму регистрации пользователя и заполнение данных о нем на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ребят такой вопрос, у меня в приложение будет первое окно где пользователь вводит имя и пароль и жмет кнопку далее, в следующем окне пишет свой возраст и жмет далее, в следующем вес и жмет далее, потом рост и так далее, после всего введенного открывается уже главное окно приложения, с помощью чего на PyQt5 лучше всего реализовать это, как лучше создавать эти окна, или это будет одно окно в котором можно листать окна или есть еще какой нибудь простой способ, поделитесь опытом или советом пожалуйста, я новичок

Comment: Tesla покажите пожалуйста что вы уже сделали для решение вашей задачи.

Comment: Я пока ничего не делал, пока тестирую только разные способы QStackedLayout(), QStackedWidget или с помощью многостраничного мастера QWizard() хочу просто услышать советы с помощью чего это можно реализовать лучше? может есть какой то простой способ

Comment: Я не знаю зачем вы все так усложняете. 
Набрали имя и пароль - нажали войти. 
Если пользователь у вас зарегистрирован - открываете главное окно, 
в котором конечно должна быть возможность внести изменения в данные, 
которые он написал когда то. 
Пользователь мог повзрослеть, набрать веса или похудеть, подрасти и т.д.

Если пользователь у вас НЕ зарегистрирован - открываете одно диалоговое окно, 
в котором предлагаете заполнить все необходимые данные для дальнейших расчетов. 
Если все необходимые данные введены - сохраняете их и пользователя, 
и открывается главное окно.